# Inserting Duplicate rows by updating its value in MYSQl

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a very complex table which is like this :-

```
Snos   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
1      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P1     6435200
2      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P1     234
3      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P1     6435
4      BD       AD2     C2      2010    P2     198448333
5      CD       AD3     C3      2011    P3     194414870
```

Now, I need to process a query that should duplicate a row where suppose p2 value is not available for that particular year or for from any of 2009 or 2010 or 2011 and put last column's value as zero in it.

So now my database should look like -

```
Snos   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
1      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P1     6435200
2      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P1     234
3      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P1     6435
4      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P2     0
5      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P2     0
6      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P2     0
7      AD       AD1     C1      2011    P3     0
8      AD       AD1     C1      2010    P3     0
9      AD       AD1     C1      2009    P3     0
10     BD       AD2     C2      2010    P2     198448333
11     BD       AD2     C2      2009    P2     0
12     BD       AD2     C2      2011    P2     0
13     BD       AD2     C2      2010    P1     0
14     BD       AD2     C2      2009    P1     0
15     BD       AD2     C2      2011    P1     0
16     BD       AD2     C2      2010    P3     0
17     BD       AD2     C2      2009    P3     0
18     BD       AD2     C2      2011    P3     0
19     CD       AD3     C3      2011    P3     194414870
20     CD       AD3     C3      2009    P3     0
21     CD       AD3     C3      2010    P3     0
22     CD       AD3     C3      2011    P1     0
23     CD       AD3     C3      2009    P1     0
24     CD       AD3     C3      2010    P1     0
25     CD       AD3     C3      2011    P2     0
26     CD       AD3     C3      2009    P2     0
27     CD       AD3     C3      2010    P2     0
```

I tried using temporary table like

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM table WHERE *Some Condition*;
    Some If Else
    Then
    UPDATE tmptable_1 SET Column6 = 0;
    INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

but its not working. Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of query you could use :

```
insert into tablename (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6) 
select "BD","AD2","C2", column4,"P2","0" 
from tablename where 
column4 in (select distinct column4 from test) 
and column4 not in (select distinct column4 from test where column5 = "P2");
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I am ignoring the `Snos` column.  This looks like an auto-numbered identity column.  The ordering should not make a difference for such a column.

The idea is to insert each group of rows (for a given year) independently.  The following query, for instance, finds the rows needed for 2009.  These are the rows that -- when grouped by most of the columns -- do not have a value for 2009:

```
insert into t(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6)
    select Column1, Column2, Column3, 2009, Column5, 0
    from table t
    group by Column1, Column2, Column3, Column5
    having sum(Column4 = 2009) = 0;
```

You can repeat this insert for 2010 and 2011.

Comment: this is great but the issue is I am not sure for which year the data is present and for which year it is not. and 2009 is not a column value its a row value. we need to place a check that if the value is not present for any of the year in 2009 or 2010 or 2011 , den insert a duplicate row with column 6 as zero

Comment: @RockR . . . That is fine.  This query determines which rows are missing the value for 2009; it then inserts them.

Comment: its is giving me following error when i am running this query - insert into data(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
    select c1, c2, c3, 2009, c5, 0
    from data
    group by c1, c2, c3, c4, c5    having sum(c4 = 2009) = 0;

**#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Aerospace & Defence-Aerospace & Defence-EADS-2009-Profit after T' for key 'Sector'**

Comment: @Rockr . . . The problem was that column4 was in the `group by`.

Comment: Great.. This worked like charm. Thank you...
I have another issue.. like suppose i have predefined that in column5 i will have p1, p2 , p3 for all the years like 2009,2010,2011. if the data is available , its fyn , if its not , it should insert it and put the last column as zero.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good question!

Try this:

```
select C.c1,
       C.c2,
       C.c3,
       A.c4,
       D.c5,
       case when B.c6 is null then 0 
            else B.c6 
       end as c6 
from (select '2011' as c4
      union all 
      select '2010' as c4
      union all 
      select '2009' as c4
      ) A
inner join 
      (select distinct c5 from tablename) D
inner join 
      (
        select distinct c1,c2,c3
        from tablename
      ) C
left outer join 
      tablename B
  on  A.c4 = B.c4
 and  D.c5 = B.c5
 and  C.c1 = B.c1
 and  C.c2 = B.c2
 and  C.c3 = B.c3
```